# How to display json data in attribut

Tags: java, android, listview, retrofit2

I'am trying to put my json data to listview attribut, but the data does not display in attribut. the data is display in RUN windows.
How to put data in attributes? i use fragment to display the listview
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flkHp.png)

My main Fragment:

```java
api = retrofitClient.getClient("http://10.8.0.2:5000/").create(Api.class);
        String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode(UtilsApi.username + ":" + UtilsApi.password);
        Log.d(TAG, "listsensor: "+api.listSensor(UtilsApi.username,UtilsApi.password,"Basic "+encoding));
        api.listSensor(UtilsApi.username, UtilsApi.password, "Basic " + encoding)
                .enqueue(new Callback<List<Sensor>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Sensor>> call, Response<List<Sensor>> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
                                MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                                JSONObject jsonRESULTS = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

                                sensors = (List<Sensor>) response.body();

                                listView.setAdapter(new SensorListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), sensors));
                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Sensor Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Sensor>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Sensor Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "INI: " + sensors);
                    }
                });
    }
```

SensorListAdapter:

```java
private Context context;
    private List<Sensor> sensors;

    public SensorListAdapter(Context context, List<Sensor> sensors){
        super(context, R.layout.list_sensor_item, sensors);
        this.context = context;
        this.sensors = sensors;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_sensor_item,parent,false);
        Sensor sensor = sensors.get(position);

        return convertView;
```

Interface:

```java
@FormUrlEncoded // List Sensor
    @POST("/api/sensors/v1.0/listsensors")
    Call<List<Sensor>> listSensor(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Header("Authorization") String authtoken);
```

Retrofitclient

```java
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
```

Comment: Sorry buddy. I can explain you with volley. But i dont know how retrofit works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Json structure, The List itself part of external Json Object. Lets say SensorsObject, So use SensorsObject as response and List will be attribute of this class.